# Improving development over ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ide, development-environment, remote-server, web-development-server

Recently I got involved in some web project development on a remote server. As for this moment, I'm OK with coding using nano over ssh, which truly is ok. But while I handle it just fine, I also think it would be more efficient to work with a proper GUI ide.

I couldn't find the solution searching google, so i decided to state my question here.

Do you familiar with a way that I can write the code locally, and automatically sync any changes to the file on my server (or any similiar solution)?

I guess it would be helpful to provide my environment details, so my presonal laptop runs **Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop LTS** with GNOME shell,
and my server runs **Ubuntu 16.04 Server LTS**.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use samba (or similar) to mount the remote server file system to your local desktop system. Then you can browse files on the server and edit them with all the tools available to you on your local machine.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I had a permission problem, but it seems to be simple anough to fix it. Thank you very much for your quick and efficient answer, have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Samba is a "good enought" solution if your server is on the same LAN as your dev client, but if you want to connect from the Internet you start running into security and configuration issues.

As you already configured ssh, you have sftp without any further effort, so I think that's the way to go for improved security. Some IDE extensions for ssh development are available. Personally, I've been using Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extension (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) and it works really well, with a nice terminal integration, git interface and, honestly, a seamless experience almost identical to local development.